# Can association be used to find the maximum key less than a specific number?

Tags: associations

Suppose we have an association `assoc`.

```
assoc = <| 1 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 5 -> 3, 7 -> 4, 20 -> 5|>;
```

Instead of checking if a specific key exists in this association, can I use `Association` to "efficiently" find the maximum key (or minimum key) which is less(larger) than  or equal to a specific value? I.e., I want to find the upper or lower bound of the given `Association` with in a time less than `O(N)` where `N` is the length of the `Association`. Please note that many kinds of balanced tree data structures allow such functionality.

In this specific example, `lower(assoc, 10) == 7` and `lower(assoc, 6) == 5` are the desired results. If it cannot be applicable for this situation, what is the best way(or data structure and so on) for this purpose in MMA?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible in less than `O(N)` since `Association` is implemented via a hash table, not a tree structure.

Comment: @StefanR It is also ok to confirm that it is not possible :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is of higher order than you are looking for but it works with an `Association`.

```
Max@Select[Keys[assoc], # <= 10 &]
(* 7 *)
```

`Keys` gets the keys, `Select` grabs those less than equal to 10, then `Max` does its job.  As function `lower`

```
lower[a_?AssociationQ, boundary_?NumericQ] := 
 Max@Select[Keys[a], # <= boundary &]

lower[assoc, 6]
(* 5 *)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help and upvoted it:) However, since it is not strictly looking for (because of the `O(N)` time complexity), I would like to wait for more answers in case there exist better solutions.

Comment: `Keys[assoc]` returns a list, which can be interpreted as a tree, so I would think that the time complexity on `lower[assoc, i]` would be linear. Try `Table[
  With[{assoc = 
     Association[Table[RandomInteger[n] -> RandomInteger[n], {n}]]},
   {n, Length@Keys[assoc], Timing[lower[assoc, 6]]}], {n, 
   Flatten[Table[10^i, {i, 7}, {3}]]}]` followed by `ListLogLogPlot[Transpose[{%[[All, 2]], %[[All, 3, 1]]}], 
 PlotRange -> All]` to see that it appears to be...